# How to print Author (Year 1 & Year 2)

Tags: citing, natbib

I am trying to achieve the following using the `natbib` package but have not have much luck. I have an author whom I am citing a lot and at some point I would the citation in the text to be in the following format:

> Einstein (1991 & 1995)

Is there a way to achieve this using the `\cite` command of `natbib` or am I asking for something too involved?

As always, many thanks for your time and help!

Comment: I use linquiry2.sty which is the style used in the linguistics journal Linguistic Inquiry.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using the `natbib` citation management package, you could provide the instruction

```
\setcitestyle{yysep={ \&}}
```

in the preamble (after loading `natbib`) to achieve your objective.

A word of caution, though: The result may look appealing if there are only two bib items being cited; however, the result will look increasingly bad if three, four, or even more items with a common author are being cited with one `\citet` instruction.

Comment: Many thanks! I suppose there is no way to handle this on a case-by-case basis, as in having this option only in the citations that you want.

Comment: Not if you want a `natbib`-based solution (or aren't looking to hack the `natbib` package in significant ways...). Just in case you care for my personal view on this formatting issue: In view of the fact that using a comma to separate years in author-year citation call-outs is nearly universal practice, I think very little is to be gained from deviating from the default.