# Biblatex: authorname (year 1; year2)

Tags: biblatex, biber

For the same author, I want a reference like `Doe (1990; 1997)` rather than `Doe (1990) and Doe (1997)`, and I want `(Doe 1990; 1997)` rather than `(Doe 1990; Doe 1997)`.

In other words, my question is very close to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277733/how-to-print-author-year-1-year-2)  but I am using `biblatex`, not `natbib`.

Is there a straightforward, simple way to do this? Apologies if I am overlooking something.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,giveninits]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Literature}
\begin{document}

I get ``\textcite{Doe1996,Doe1990}" but I want ``Doe (1990; 1997)". I get ``\autocite{Doe1996,Doe1990}" but I want ``(Doe 1990; 1997)"
\end{document}
```

Comment: `style=authoryear-comp` should give you the desired result. From the `biblatex` documentation: "A compact variant of the authoryearstyle which prints the author only once if subsequent references passed to a single citation command share the same author. ". See also: [Biblatex - Combine Papers using citet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/534371/134144) for a similar question.

Comment: This does not work (result unchanged). I am puzzled. It should!? Playing with ``csquotes``, ``giveninits`` etc. does seem to not make a difference.

When I add
``\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}`` and ``\textcite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}`` to my MWE above, I get ``Knuth (1984, 1986)" as desired but the other references remain the same.

Comment: Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that contains two sample entries with which you get the desired compressed output and two entries for which the compression deso nt work as expected. Probably the issue is hidden in the entry in the .bib file.

Comment: `style=authoryear-comp,` as suggested by leandriis should get you pretty far. The only difference is that it uses a comma to separate years and not a semicolon, but that could be changed if desired. If you don't get 'compact' citations despite using `style=authoryear-comp,`, you need to show us a compilable example complete with `.bib` entries (you can use `biblatex-examples.bib` and the two entries `knuth:ct:a` and `knuth:ct:b`). The following works for me https://gist.github.com/moewew/4f45ab210f29494406b7b08848d817a1

Comment: I am having troubles creating the MWEB (see my question there: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407). filecontents does not seem to work with more than one bib entry for me.

Comment: By default `filecontents` will not overwrite an existing file. This is a problem when your are experimenting and adding entries one by one. Of course you could always remove the automatically generated `.bib` file when you add a new entry, but that is cumbersome. There are ways to allow `filecontents` to overwrite existing files. In a current LaTeX version write `\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}` instead of `\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}` to allow overwriting. In an older LaTeX version load `\usepackage{filecontents}`.

Comment: @moewe: Terrific!!! Thanks!

Comment: Great! Looking forward to the MWE.

Comment: I solved it! It turns out that ``Doe, Terence`` and ``Doe, Terry`` are treated as nonidentical people, which seems legit. Renaming one of them yields the desired result.

Comment: Ahh, the classic `uniquename` option. If you want to stick with the original names as they are on the publication, you may be interested https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864.

Comment: Since this question is now basically two issues in one (which style and something about `uniquename`) it probably isn't that useful to close the question as a duplicate. So I suggest you either ask leandriis to turn their comments into an answer (with an added note about `uniquename`) or you write a self-answer so this can be wrapped up.

Comment: Dear moewe and @leandriis, would either of you like to post the answer? Otherwise I am happy to do so. Thanks again for helping me solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching the style from `style=authoryear` to `style=authoryear-comp` should result in an output quite close to the desired one.

> From the `biblatex` documentation: "A compact variant of the
> authoryearstyle which prints the author only once if subsequent
> references passed to a single citation command share the same author
> ".

See also: Biblatex - [Combine Papers using citet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/534371/134144) for  a similar question.

---

By default, the separator between subsequent years is a comma, while your example shows a semicolon instead. If you want to change the output accordingly, you could redefine `\compcitedelim` according to your needs:

```
\renewcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
```

---

If a single person published using two different versions of their first name, the compression might not work as expected since the author is treated as two different authors who share their last name. To turn off this behaviour without having to alter (homogenize) the first names in the bib file, you can use the package option `uniquename = false`.

See also: [biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134544/134144) for a related question.